# Infer exact object property type when returning it via function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given the following state:

```
  type DataType = {
        a: string,
        b: number,
        c: boolean
  }

  const testObject: DataType = {
        a: 'Dummy',
        b: 1,
        c: true
  }

  type A = typeof testObject['a'] // string
  type B = typeof testObject['b'] // number
  type C = typeof testObject['c'] // boolean
```

It is clear that I can get the type of each property of the `DataType` object by using either `typeof testObject['a']` or `DataType['a']`.

*However,* when I try to do the same via accessor inside a function, I cannot get the exact type of the property I am accessing. Example below:

```
  function testAccess<T>(o: T, p: keyof T): T[typeof p] {
        return o[p]
  }

  const a = testAccess(testObject, 'a') // string | number | boolean
```

Am I missing something, and is there any way to narrow down the type to the exact key that we are sending?

TS playground link: [https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwD...](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAVc0C8UDeAoKf9wBcUAzsAE4CWAdgOYA0u%20eARsdQK4C2LE5jzPAGNiLAPZiANhDjVsAX2zZpwKMAhkA8iwBWEIcGLxEKSFAw5BUIlADkMblxC2BgtlACMr5iLXkOEApKoGYAguZqqGIAZmoawNp6BgDatnC2ALpQAPTZpBQ0tNgh0ABCESUxcVq6%20sCpLJk5eZw8fMWoUADCFVGx6jVJ9bZCTblQ4lIyckrRHNQGlGLU1cChQkIaJAA8SAB8ABRixEj0UGDEANYQIFVIAJQnyZWxYFmWguQQwBzkK2LJN5BbBCZZkawVeLrTYkEgHAYJWoGM5pWz3Zr5Kh0KAAHygrV45FxEwk0lkQA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to include the key type as a generic parameter:

```
function testAccess<T, P extends keyof T>(o: T, p: P): T[P] {
      return o[p]
}

const a = testAccess(testObject, 'a') // string
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=22&ssc=48&pln=18&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAVc0C8UDeAoKf9wBcUAzsAE4CWAdgOYA0u%20eARsdQK4C2LE5jzPAGNiLAPZiANhDjVsAX2zZpwKMAhkA8iwBWEIcGLxEKSFAw5BUIlADkMblxC2BgtlACMr5iLXkOEApKoGYAguZqqGIAZmoawNp6BgDatnC2ALpQAPTZpBQ0tNgh0ABCESUxcVq6%20sCpLJk5eZw8fMWoUADCFVGx6jVJ9bZCTblQ4lIyckrRHNQGlGLU1cChQkIaJAA8SPRQAApQEAAe6tQAJiRQANYQIFVIAHwAFGLEe1BgxAcAlB-JA5ZSyCcgQYAccgrMTJMAZILYITLMjWCrxdabEgkF4DBK1Az7NK2X7NfJUOhAA)